# how can I write an equation (1) from reference 2 like this in Latex [2, eqn. (1)]?

Tags: cross-referencing

how can I write an equation  (1) from reference 2 like this in Latex [2, eqn. (1)]?

Comment: Try with `\cite[eqn.~(1)]{<citation>}`.

Comment: \cite[eqn.~(1)]{<\cite{zhang2021evolution}>} this is giving an error

Comment: No, just `\cite[eqn.~(1)]{zhang2021evolution}`.

Comment: Thank you. It works!